# How to call factory method in other file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am using FactoryGirl in my rails application. I have following code snippet

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :pub_company, :class => Company do |c|
    c.name "Dixons Group"
    c.address "1500 Martin Ave"
    c.city "Santa Clara"
    c.state "CA"
  end
end

FactoryGirl.buid(:pub_company)
```

Above code can creates a record fine. I am trying to create more data as similar to above one. so, i am using

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :new do
    FactoryGirl.create(:pub_company)
    FactoryGirl.create(:adv_user)
    FactoryGirl.create(:adv_setting)
    FactoryGirl.create(:adv_ad)
  end
end
```

it fails for me. Is this possible using factorygirl to call a different factory and create a record?

Comment: Is `build` here a typo: `FactoryGirl.buid(:pub_company)`?

Comment: home/gems/factory_girl-4.3.0/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb:24:in `find': Factory not registered: pub_company (ArgumentError)                Also, tried with FactoryGirl.build getting the same error.

Comment: why have you here `factory_girl_r ails` the space?

Comment: also: `FactoryGirl.buid(:pub_company)` you have a mistake in syntax: and that line in the first snippet isn't needed anyway. Then, you also shell to have factories: `adv_user`, `adv_setting`, `adv_ad` defined.

Comment: And second, you shell to define field, to which you wish to assign other created factories.

Comment: Has the answer been helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Since, the FactoryGirl is used mostly for testing models, I show the sample models, and factories, spec for the *new* model.

**app/models/new.rb**

```
class New < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :company_id
  belongs_to :company
end
```

**app/models/company.rb**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :address, :city, :state
  has_many :news
end
```

**spec/factories/company_factory.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do |c|
    c.name "Dixons Group"
    c.address "1500 Martin Ave"
    c.city "Santa Clara"
    c.state "CA"
  end
end
```

**spec/factories/new_factory.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :new do
    company { FactoryGirl.create :company }
    # adv_user { FactoryGirl.create :adv_user }
    # adv_setting { FactoryGirl.create :adv_setting }
    # adv_ad { FactoryGirl.create :adv_ad }
  end
end
```

NOTE: You shell to have `adv_user`, `adv_setting`, `adv_ad` defined also.

**spec/models/new_spec.rb**

```
describe New do
  it 'Test new model' do
    new_instance = FactoryGirl.create :new
    new_instance.pub_company.name.should == "Dixons Group"
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: when tring above, it dosent create any record. It can produces           No examples found.


Finished in 0.00007 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures

Comment: @Pez This means that you haven't defined a test sample in rspec/cucumber... Create a test that shell use the Factory.

Comment: All files are under spec/factories

Comment: @Pez Show your specs in your post, not all but that part that cerates the factory and test it

Comment: dont move, just show parts of them inside your post by editing it.

Comment: gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@aer-ui/gems/factory_girl-4.3.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_list.rb:51:in `ensure_attribute_not_defined!': Attribute already defined: pub_company (FactoryGirl::AttributeDefinitionError)

Comment: How do you create `new` factory?

Comment: I dont see your code, and can't read it mentally, please either share the code, or debug as follows: remove all unnecessary factories, attain the work example code: then add factories one-by-one till reach the alid result as you wish

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43755/discussion-between-pez-and-majioa)

Comment: @Pez I edited the answer showing you sample models, factiried for them, and the spec.